# iOS DynamoDB Object Mapper load does not return all the attributes

Tags: swift2, amazon-dynamodb

I'm running below function in my iPad app to get an Item by it's hash key (IdName).
This table only contains an Hashkey (No Range key available) but when I run this, It returns an result object which contains only the HashKey Value (The same which I pass). The other property (IdValue) is not there in the result. What am I doing wrong here?

```
func getCurrentFinalReportNumber()->Int
{
    let dynamoDBObjectMapper = AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper.defaultDynamoDBObjectMapper()

    var currentId :Int = -1

    dynamoDBObjectMapper .load(DDBIDStoreTableRow.self, hashKey: "FinalReportNumber", rangeKey: nil) .continueWithExecutor(AWSExecutor.mainThreadExecutor(), withBlock: { (task:AWSTask!) -> AnyObject! in
        if (task.error == nil) {
            if (task.result != nil) {
                let resultRow :DDBIDStoreTableRow = task.result as! DDBIDStoreTableRow
                print(resultRow.IdValue)
                currentId = Int(resultRow.IdValue!)
            }
        } else {
            print("Error: \(task.error)")

            let alert = SCLAlertView()
            alert.addButton("Close", colorButtonBackground: Constants.InspectionTypes.colorClose) {}
            alert.showCloseButton = false
            alert.showError("", subTitle: (task.error?.description)!)


        }
        return nil
    }).waitUntilFinished()


    return currentId
} 



class DDBIDStoreTableRow :AWSDynamoDBObjectModel ,AWSDynamoDBModeling  {

    var IdName:String? //HK
    var IdValue:Int? = -1


    class func dynamoDBTableName() -> String! {
        return AWSIDStoreDynamoDBTableName
    }

    class func hashKeyAttribute() -> String! {
        return "IdName"
    }


    //MARK: NSObjectProtocol hack
    override func isEqual(object: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
        return super.isEqual(object)
    }

    override func `self`() -> Self {
        return self
    }

}
```

[image: Snapshot of the table being queried]

Answer (score 0):

Just found the mistake. Problem is in the data type of the mapping class. Earlier it was

```
var IdValue:Int? = -1
```

But once I change the Int to NSNumber as below. It started to work fine

```
var IdValue:NSNumber? = -1
```